# how to get value from database by id

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table.

> 1. newuser (id,office_id,username)
> 2. offices (office_id,office_name)

When user login I got his `office_id`

- I want to fetch his `office_name` from `offices` table

The session is working :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['office']))
{
    $id_office = $_SESSION['office'];
}
```

I wrote this code to fetch office_name but dose not work

```
$query =("SELECT office_name FROM offices WHERE office_id = '$id_office'");
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
        $office_name = $_POST['office_name'];
}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure this is the problematic part: `$office_name = $_POST['office_name'];`. I don't know how to do it in `mysqli`, but `$_POST` does not contain the result of your query

Comment: What happens with the code? `$result` would need to be fetched (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to get a result. You also should use parameterized queries.

Comment: I suggest finding some video tutorials, they will help you more then a few way word comments on SO, Not that my fellow posters aren't great (I have the utmost respect for them).  Just you can only convey so much info in the format that SO provides.

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Even [`real_escape_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2469308) cannot secure it completely. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually fetching the result. Try changing the if block to fetch the result using [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $office_name = $row['office_name'];
}
```

Note that `$_POST` contains data submitted to the PHP page by a form, not the results of MySQL queries.